# How to rewrite openssl_open function using openssl_decrypt in php?

Tags: php, openssl

I want to decrypt data encrypted with `openssl_seal`. Function `openssl_open` works as expected:

```
openssl_open($sealed, $open, $env_key, $priv_key)) {
echo $open;
```

But I got no luck when I was trying to rewrite it this way:

```
openssl_private_decrypt($env_key, $env_key_decrypted, $priv_key);
$open = openssl_decrypt($sealed, "rc4", $env_key_decrypted);
echo $open;
```

Thanks in advance for any help!